# Browser sync not working locally with html5mode

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

I'm working on an Angular app and having an issue locally with browser-sync. When I edit a page locally browser-sync tries to reload the page but I get **Cannot GET /weeks5-8.html** I had the same issue for the live version of the site but fixed it by adding the htaccess file.

I have tried this connect-modrewrite solution but it didn't work [First solution tried.](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/323)

I've also tried this historyApiFallback solution but again it didn't work [Second solution tried.](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/708)

I'm curious if anyone has had this issue and if they have solved it. The site is [live.](http://marshmallowandmammy.com/) and the repo for the site is [here.](https://github.com/mike-griffin87/marshmallowandmammy)

My browser-sync task is as follows:

```
browserSync({
server: {
  baseDir: './dist/',
  middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
}
```

The Angular file is as follows:

```
angular.module('marshmallowAndMammy',['ngRoute'])
.controller('mmController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', MmController])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider.
when("/", {templateUrl:"/partials/homepage.html"}).
when("/weeks5-8.html", {templateUrl:"/partials/week5-8.html"});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.